# Refactoring legacycode to CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, refactoring

I’m working on a project which involves converting an existing PHP solution to CakePHP. This is my first project that requires some nontrivial migration knowledge, and I got to a point that I have reached a major roadblock.

The way I approached this project was to divide the current code into components, and then migrate these components to CakePHP’s standards. One thing I overlooked was how these components are connected to each other.

To make matters worse, the current code doesn’t have clear documentation or comments and it doesn’t use MVC standards. Also, the developers responsible for the current code aren’t easily available for questions.

My question is… if you were assigned to work on such a project, how would you approach this migration from the legacy code set to a CakePHP model?

Answer (score 2):

The answer for that is pretty easy: Don't look at the garbage behind the fancy facade.

Don't try to understand the very often totally silly and bad quality code, instead analyze the applications business logic and workflow. Ask your client if he has up to date specs for the application and get them.

Build the application from the ground up. Everything else is unclean, realistically it is more than unlikely that you can simply copy and paste old code to the new app. This doesn't even work with bad written CakePHP apps and I have some experience with really really bad code because I do code reviews in our company.

If you're new to CakePHP and MVC I recommend you to spend time to learn the framework, MVC and other basic principles like DRY, KIS well to not just pile up garbage again under the hood of a MVC framework.

- http://book.cakephp.org/
- http://api.cakephp.org/
- http://training.cakephp.org/

Comment: @Raisen I had same scenario few months before and BURZUM has given you correct way to approach. Try to work in AGILE for such project where you convert your business logic in to Modules and then to small stories and analyse them with current systems. This way you can find what is useful and can remove the garbage code. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you've been refactoring in components is great. So you've already started out well.

I don't know the details of course, but I generally advise against big-bang refactorings or rewriting (in that regard I respectfully disagree with @floriank if he means that with "building the application from the ground up).

I specialize in technical debt and legacy code and what I always recommend is to create a suite of automated tests for the existing application first. Create a safety net for your changes. Quite often, unit tests are near impossible in old projects that weren't written with unit tests in mind. What you can do then is write end-to-end tests. Maybe you can mock out a few things like the database. That would make your tests faster and easier to set up. But sometimes even that is impossible, unfortunately. In that case, you'll want to have a system set up that you can mess about with. Possibly, you could take a backup of a database and restore it each time before you run your tests.

Then, ignore all the underlying pieces of logic. Regard the app as a black box and make API calls, or automate the UI. And verify the results.

You can use something like [Behat](https://docs.behat.org/en/latest/) for this, which uses the Gherkin language to write readable tests. Or you could run Postman requests.

Once you have a suite of tests, you can start making changes to the underlying code (as long as it is under test). Improve the code so that it will match with CakePHP standards better. While you do so, you may see that certain components can be put under unit test after a while.

But as you make changes, you have your end-to-end test suite to verify you didn't break anything.

At a certain point in time, you may have to make some (more-or-less) big bang changes when you switch to CakePHP. But by then, I hope you have more unit tests and you still have your end-to-end test suite.

In case of APIs, you could even put a load balancer or API gateway in between the incoming requests and your apps. Then, duplicate the requests. One going to the old app and one to the new. Then return the old response, but log it and also log the new response. Then you can compare the two and hopefully, they're the same. Watch out with requests that have side-effects though.

The loadbalancer is useful anyway, because when you go live, it's nice to be able to switch back to the old app, just in case.

It's definitely a long process, but not impossible.

A final note: agree on the status of the old project. If you're working on something new, but the old still gets feature requests, you also have to put those in the new project. Which easily becomes a nightmare. Which is why it's better to refactor the old. Bugfixes and new features then are part of the effort and don't have to be done twice.

Hope that helps!

Comment: any affiliation with behat? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: @starball Nope, I'm not even a PHP programmer (unless a bit on the side). I had to Google what the PHP implementation of Cucumber/Gherkin was.